# Run a function after internet explorer finishes loading in Excel VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

```
Function GetIE() As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set GetIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End Function

Dim appIE As Object ' InternetExplorer.Application
Dim sURL As String

sURL = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pppp/"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set appIE = GetIE
appIE.Visible = True

With appIE
    .navigate sURL & "login.php"
    .Visible = True
End With
```

I want to call a function after internet explorer finishes loading. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
With appIE
    .navigate sURL & "login.php"
    .Visible = True

    ' Enter a do loop until the *readyState* property of IE object becomes equal to 4
    Do
        If .readyState = 4 Then ' check the *readyState* property
            ' Call your function here
            Exit Do
        Else
            ' IE is not ready, allow other application events to run
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop

End With
```

Comment: Please would you elaborate on your answer, explaining what the code does and how it solves the problem, this will help others who see your answer in the future